# Catching in Ruby java.lang.threaddeath

Tags: java, ruby

I have a ruby script that raises a `java.lang.threaddeath` error. This doesn't stop my script but is returns a pop-up message that I would like to prevent by correctly catching this error.

The error originates from the following statement:

```
system("C:\\cpdf.exe -list-bookmarks -utf8 \"#{filePath}\" > \"#{bookmarkPath}\"")
```

I have tried to catch the exception as follows, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
begin
    system("C:\\cpdf.exe -list-bookmarks -utf8 \"#{filePath}\" > \"#{bookmarkPath}\"")
    rescue Exception => exceptionType
end
```

Would someone have more experience with this type of issue, or any idea how to catch it correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why I lost all formatting in my message. Please find below the code I tried.

Comment: begin
  system("C:\\cpdf.exe -list-bookmarks -utf8 \"#{filePath}\" > \"#{bookmarkPath}\"")
 rescue Exception => exceptionType
 end